# Making Eclipse aware of a new android custom view

Tags: android, eclipse

After I write a new custom view inside an android library project, how do I make Eclipse aware of it and add it to the "Custom & Library Views" tab (so I can use it inside the GUI editor) ?

Comment: The "Palette" at the left should have a category named "Custom & Library Views" at the bottom which should automatically contian it. Otherwise just add a `<com.mycode.MyView>` thing to the xml by hand

Comment: As a side note - in the TicTacToeLib sample program that comes with the Android SDK the custom view GameView auto displayed in that tab and so is any new class that inherits from View, however my custom view inherits from LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

As it's written here: [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound)

> The usual starting point is a Layout of some kind, **so create a class
>   that extends a Layout**. Perhaps in the case of a Combo box we might use
>   a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.

So your view can look like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class LayoutX extends LinearLayout {

    public LayoutX(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.
              getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inf.inflate(pl.infografnet.GClasses.R.layout.layout_file, this, true);
    }
}
```

and layout_file.xaml can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" >

    </Button>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my case it is enough to make Eclipse see `LayoutX` component at "Custom & Library Views" tab.